# How to make make a variable undetermined type in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

For example I have a node that contains

```
Node * next;

[X] data;
```

How could I fill in [X]  so that I can make 'data' either types A, B, C, D, which I determine later on. I tried making it void, but that just lead to errors. I am using it to have a linked list holding one variable, which could be of types A B C D.

Comment: Templates, inheritance...

Comment: I also tried enum X {a ,b ,c ,d};

Comment: I'll cook up a small example, since I don't really know the context of your question, it may or may not solve the problem you're facing. Maybe someone will beat me to it!

Comment: enums are basically collections of named integer values that go in ascending order

Comment: If you use a void pointer for your `next` you can point to nodes which hold different types of data.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is I want to have a node that has contains one thing, data. Howevever, the type for data I want to change as I add the node in. So a node could be holding a class B, pointing to another node with a class A. Sorry if I am not making sense I am new to c++

Comment: Well if all of your types `A,B,C,D` share a lot of properties, then inheritance is likely what you want to use. Here's the example I cooked up: http://ideone.com/VD9azI EDIT: worth noting, I don't clean up my memory leaks! Always be careful when you use pointers like this, I just didn't want to add extra stuff for you as you try to understand inheritance, but if you're dealing with pointers you should know your memory management!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use templates, or void pointers (and you should *never* use void pointers in C++ when templates would do the trick).

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node * next;
    T data;
};
```

Now `Node<int>` and `Node<float>` are different types.  You can use *any* type as the argument, as long as that type can be default-constructed.  If you want to *restrict* `T` to be one of a set of types then the answer is a bit more involved, but usually there is no good reason to do this.

If, on the other hand, you want a *single* linked list to be able to hold *many different types* then `T` has to be able to represent all of those types.  For example if all of the types you want to store derive from a common class `A` then you could use `Node<std::unique_ptr<A>>` and then you would be able to store `A` or any more-derived-subtype of `A` in that particular list.

If you want one single list to be able to hold elements of any of a set of unrelated types, you need to build a "variant" structure that is capable of storing all of them, as well as some field indicating which type it currently holds, then use that variant structure as the type argument to `Node`.

If you want one single list to be able to hold elements of *any type at all* then you don't have many options besides using a void pointer for `data`: `Node<void *>`.  But there are many caveats to this technique, mainly deciding who owns the pointed-to allocations, and figuring out the right way to delete them.

(Note that even though I wrote `Node * next`, `next` is actually a `Node<T> *`.  Within the `Node` class, the template arguments are implied.)

Answer (score 0):

C++ is strongly typed, so all types need to be knows at compile time.

You can look into using templates:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T s)
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

template void f<double>(double); // instantiates f<double>(double)
template void f<>(char); // instantiates f<char>(char), template argument deduced
template void f(int); // instantiates f<int>(int), template argument deduced
```

example from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

or A,B,C & D could all inherit from one class, and you could then store them as the parent class.
There is a lot more to it than I can easily show in one small example, so here is a [helpful link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Basically, as a conceptional example, you could have a parent class `vehicle` and have a list of `vehicle`s.
You would then actually generate a couple of `car`s, `motorbike`s and `truck`s (which all inherit from `vehicle`) that are stored in the list (as they are all `vehicle`s as well as their own sub-class.